# React build is unable to load fonts correctly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

In the development mode the fonts and in general, all the assets, are successfully loaded by React. The problem comes when I create the build of the project and upload it to my express-based server: the application looks for fonts in a wrong directory and so does not find them. The images instead are loaded correctly and are required to this URL: */static/media*.
Fonts are searched in this directory: */static/css/static/media*; this is, of course, wrong because the fonts, in production, are in the same folder from which the images are loaded and the path that is searched for does not exist.

Fonts are loaded, in a scss file, in this way:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Rawson';
  src: url("../assets/fonts/RawsonPro-Medium.otf") format('opentype');
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

I am aware that there are other similar problems, especially on github, but I can't really solve it. Many problems seem to have been resolved with an update of the react-scripts package, and with the use of the "homepage" property.

```
  "homepage": "./"
```

Although I have done so, I cannot find a solution.
Thanks to those who decide to help me.

Comment: What's your build setup? Are you using create-react-app? Basically, you want your build to generate paths that are appropriate for your deployment environment. For example, if your app is deployed at https://example.com/ then your assets should be relative to the root (/). Whereas, if your app is deployed at https://example.com/app then your assets should point to /app. If you use create-react-app, homepage is used to determine the path: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths

Comment: @Hans Yes, I'm using create-react-app. My react app is served for any server route (apart from those dedicated to the API), so the assets should be relative to the root /. What I don't understand is what is the cause of this react error in loading the fonts, because the directory in which they are searched (/static/css/static/media) is totally wrong, and  it has nothing to do with the real one (/static/media).
I think the problem lies in the way relative paths are handled in CSS, but I would prefer not to eject my app, so I cannot access the webpack configuration (at least I think).

Comment: Ah, sorry I misunderstood the problem. So this is an issue with how the URL is resolved by the Webpack loader. I don't know what the solution would be, but looking at the docs, it may be that the URL must start with `./` (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/)

Answer (score 0):

in you webpack config test it

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'fonts/'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  watch: true
}
```

it should be created in out file path that you written

Comment: Thanks for your interest @tmohammad78, but I would prefer not to eject my app (generated with create-react-app), and therefore I don't think I can access the webpack configuration (I'm new in this scope, so correct me if I'm wrong).